# Azure Notifcation Hub CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync not failing but Installation not being created

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have an ASP.NET Web Api that is registering Android and iOS installations in our Azure Notification Hub. It creates a HubClient using a connection string

```
this.azureHub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
    "Endpoint=sb://OUR-HUB-NS.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=tK/SEXXXXXXXXXXX/7LUtvRoNt+HjToFmP+T++yW5g=",
    "OUR-HUB");
```

We then create an installation using this code

```
try
{
    await azureHub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation, token);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    this.logger.LogError(e, "CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync failed with" + e.Message);
    return false;
}

return true;
```

When I had the NoticationHubClient incorrectly configured I was getting 401 errors and if I pass in nonsense for the installation data I will get a 400. Currently the call does not throw an error so I asm going to assume what I am passing is correct and it can successfully connect to the hub. However registrations are not being created. If i try and get the installation after it is created with

```
GetInstallationAsync(installation.InstallationId)
```

I get an error saying the installation cannot be found and if I try and get all registrations i get an empty list

```
var registrations = await azureHub.GetAllRegistrationsAsync(0);
```

Further confirmation that my installations are not being created is that if I use the "Test Send" in Azure Portal I get "Message was successfully sent, but there were **no matching targets**." for either Apple or Android platform

What is happening to my registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the Notification Hub with a different name, in the same namespace and everything just started working.

I then recreated the non-working hub in Azure Portal and it now all works.

All I can say is that I had previously deleted the hub using the OSS [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) and perhaps that deleted the hub in a way that Azure didn't like.

Not the answer I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Calls to `CreateOrUpdateInstallation` run without error, but also do not create the installation.

I think I figured out what the problem is. I believe there is a bug in Azure Notification Hubs where if you delete an "Installation" and then create the exact same one, even after waiting several minutes after the delete, it does not create it.

There must be a caching layer that doesn't get updated on delete because if you change anything about the installation (tags, userId, etc.) it does create.

I thought creating a new Notification Hub had solved it, but that was a coincidence because the new hub didn't have a deleted Installation.I was able to reproduce the behavior in both the new and old Hubs. And on a call with Microsoft support, they could confirm from the logs that there was no error and it was not creating the installation.

Proposed work-around: add a randomly generated tag every time and it should defeat the cache.